# What is curl doing with -d and -X GET?

Tags: http, curl, newrelic

I'm looking to this snippet of code:

```
curl -X GET 'https://api.newrelic.com/v2/applications/1622/metrics/data.json' \
 -H 'X-Api-Key:30f4ec24a1f7dd9998a536b05840b17f7d42c7c1' -i \
 -d 'names[]=EndUser&names[]=EndUser/Apdex&values[]=call_count&values[]=average_response_time&values[]=score&summarize=true'
```

from "[Listing your app ID and metric data](https://docs.newrelic.com/docs/apis/rest-api-v2/application-examples-v2/listing-your-app-id-metric-data-v2)".

But curl's [man page](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html) only talks about `-d/--data` in the context of POST requests, so, what's really happening here in terms of the HTTP request sent to the server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`-d` with GET request just sends a query string, however the endpoint where data are sent must be set to consume `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` content type - have just checked that.

In general it's weird and I wouldn't implement it in such a way.

When such query is sent to java servlet - the body is accessible via.. `getInputStream()` method [sic!].